# has_many through and select with order not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to list Users and order them by EventViews but I keep getting an error:

```
Unknown column 'views_count' in 'order clause': SELECT `users`.`id` AS t0_r0, `users`.`email` AS t0_r1, `users`.`encrypted_password` AS t0_r2, `users`.`reset_password_token` AS t0_r3, `users`.`reset_password_sent_at` AS t0_r4, `users`.`remember_created_at` AS t0_r5, `users`.`sign_in_count` AS t0_r6, `users`.`current_sign_in_at` AS t0_r7, `users`.`last_sign_in_at` AS t0_r8, `users`.`current_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r9, `users`.`last_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r10, `users`.`created_at` AS t0_r11, `users`.`updated_at` AS t0_r12, `users`.`user_type` AS t0_r13, `event_views`.`id` AS t1_r0, `event_views`.`event_id` AS t1_r1, `event_views`.`ip` AS t1_r2, `event_views`.`created_at` AS t1_r3, `event_views`.`updated_at` AS t1_r4, `event_views`.`session_id` AS t1_r5, `event_views`.`is_unique` AS t1_r6, `event_views`.`user_agent` AS t1_r7, `event_views`.`promoter_id` AS t1_r8 FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `event_views` ON `event_views`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`  ORDER BY views_count desc
```

Here's my code:

```
User.all.includes(:event_views).select('user.*, count(event_views.id) as "views_count"').order("views_count desc").each

#models

User
has_many :event_views, :through => :events

Events
has_many :event_views

EventView
#nothing relevant
```

They are all related in the normal fashion (event_id, user_id, etc)

Comment: no, i want to count event_views, not events

Comment: Did you copy the query correctly in your question? You have `user.*` instead of `users.*`. In addition, I would expect you to get an error indicating the lack of a `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to remember here:

1. You are calling `includes` on `User.all` which is an `Array`, so this will fail.
2. As @peteralfvin pointed out already, you should have `users.*` not `user.*`.  But this will be a problem because you are using `count` aggregate function.  This means you need to include every column in `users` table in your `group by` clause.
3. You should not use `includes` in this case because `includes` will include all the columns from all the included tables in the query.  This is because you are selecting columns from both `users` and `event_views`.  If you remove `count(event_views.id) as "views_count"` then you'll see that only the specified columns from `users` table will be selected.

That being said, this query should work for you:

```
users = User.joins(:event_views).select('users.id, count(event_views.id) as views_count').order("views_count desc")
# Then access your views_count for user with: 
users.first.views_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do this in the SQL query, if you are getting all the records anyway:

```
users = User.includes(:event_views).all
users.sort_by!{ |user| user.event_views.count }
```

If you want them sorted the other way just tack a `.reverse!` on the end of the last line.